# How to use github repo as like CDN server for uploading assets file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github, cdn

I am learning ruby on rails. I am developing a rails 5 application.
I don't want to use amazon s3 service for containing my assets files.
I want to use github for serving my assets files as like CDN.

But I am facing a problem, I have dynamic file and image upload system.
So therefore, When I will upload my files and images, all files and images will be uploaded in a github repository (assume, I have a git repo named `busket`; so, all images and files will be uploaded in `busket` repo from my server and will serve all assets from rails application).

So, how can I make github as like CDN ? Please help me about this issue.

Comment: Why don't you want to use S3? Is it too slow (just asking because you mentioned you want to serve files like a CDN)? Since GitHub would be even slower than S3, that might be a bad choice.

Comment: just use jsdelivr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Encode image to base 64
ref: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html

2.) Make API call to github

ref: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file

This will upload and return the url of your stored image within github, store that in your database.

Although you stated you didn't want to use S3, the paperclip gem makes it very streamlined.

Answer (score 3):

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/username/repository@master/file
```

username = name of the user of github
repository = name of github repo
file = actual name of the file

Comment: Actually `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/username/repository@master/file`

Answer (score 2):

I feel that it would be a generally bad idea to upload images and general types of content files to GitHub for long terms storage.  GitHub was designed to be a repository provider for Git, not as a NoSQL or other type of data store.  Updating files in GitHub would require making a commit to a particular branch.  Hence, every time you change an image file, it would require a new commit.  This won't scale, because Git does not handle binary files well.

So if you need a long term data store for your image and content files, I would suggest looking into tools which were designed for that, such as Amazon's S3, Google Cloud Storage, and things similar to this.

Comment: I echo Tim's concerns, it's definitely better to ship files like this from a proper CDN, or an object store like S3/GCS.

[GitHub now supports Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) so it _is_ possible to store large binary files (like images) much more efficiently - it's just not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Tim its generally a bad idea. 
However if you still want to use Git as a File Server append

> ?raw=true

at the end of the URI.
For example

> https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/ewah/bitmap.c?raw=true

would give you the contents of the file.